# Fix double commas, periods and other common typos

Tags: jquery, textarea, autocorrect

I want too check for a series of common typos and fix them live, while the user is typing in an html textarea.

It's a common list of typos, such as two periods, space before punctuation, no space after punctuation, and so on..

I know it's a common problem but I'm not being able to find a proper jquery plugin or something along those lines.

Alternatively if the is no such plugin... I could use some help with the regexes to use.

Comment: lol @ the double period.  idk about any plugin of this type but the regex wouldn't be hard.  You would need to tie it in with the keyup event.

Comment: I guess you don't expect anybody to type something like `$12,000.00` or `"...some phrase..."`?

Comment: Not at all, each entry will be a kind of announcement from a local newspaper, like auctions stuff like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some jQuery code that removes double commas and double periods as typed:

HTML:

```
<textarea class="autoCorrect" rows="5" cols="40">Some initial text</textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".autoCorrect").keypress(function() {
    var obj = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        var text = obj.value;
        var selStart = obj.selectionStart;
        var newText = text.replace(/,{2,}|\.{2,}/, function(match, index) {
            if (index < selStart) {
                selStart -= (match.length - 1);  // correct the selection location
            }
            return(match.substr(0,1));
        });
        if (newText != text) {
            obj.value = newText;
            obj.selectionStart = obj.selectionEnd = selStart;
        }
    }, 1);
})
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/XbZrS/.

It should be obvious how you extend it to other double characters by just adding them to the regex.  If you wanted to catch other events that could modify the text such as cut, paste and drag/drop, you'd have to hook this logic up to those other events too.

Comment: Note that the setTimeout is in there so you can see the text in the field after the key has been processed.  It could also be done without the setTimeout to look at the insertion point and see where the current keystroke would go and decide whether it would cause a double and then block that key, but that's a little more work.

Comment: Worked out [this plugin](https://gist.github.com/1194193) based on your tip. I'm marking your answer as accepted.